# Compilation of a 2d array and a 1d array

Tags: list-manipulation

With a list say `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, …}` and a list `{z1}`, what is the best way to create a list `{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z1}, {x3, y3, z1}, …}`?

Comment: `Join[#, {z1}] & /@ {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`PadRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight):

```
PadRight[
    {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}},
    {Automatic, 3},
    z1
]
```

> {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z1}}

Or [`ArrayPad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad):

```
ArrayPad[
    {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}},
    {{0,0},{0,1}},
    z1
]
```

> {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z1}, {x3, y3, z1}}

Answer (score 4):

```
n = 1000000;
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
b = ConstantArray[0., 1];
c = Join[a, ConstantArray[b, Length[a]], 2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.016

Answer (score 3):

```
xy = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}
z = {z1, z2, ...}
xyz = Partition[Flatten[Riffle[xy, z]], 3]
```

and you're done. `Riffle` also works with just one z-value: it'll do exactly what you asked, after re-reading your question more carefully.

**Explanation:**

First, `Riffle[list1, list2 **or** element, so just z1 works, too]` makes

```
{ {x1, y1}, z1, {x2, y2}, z2, ...}
```

then, `Flatten[list]` makes

```
{ x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ... }
```

finally, `Partition[list, 3]` turns it into

```
{ {x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, ...}
```

Comment: This is NOT what the question asked though. The question wanted to add a single constant `z1` element to the right of each sublist.

Comment: @MarcoB I think the question is open to question.  The OP uses the term "a list {z1}` rather than just `z1` and the above answer works whether there's a single term in the list (`{z1}`) or multiple terms (`{z1,z2,z3}`) or just a single constant (`z1`).  I also say that because of the odd use of `compilation` rather than `concatenation`.

Comment: @JimB I see. On the other hand, in their post OP included a "desired output" with a constant `z1`, and they accepted an answer using a constant `z1`... I ready the "list `{z1}`" to mean "a list containing a single element, z1". Plenty of functions in MMA return a list even when the output is a single element, for consistency, so I could see the requirement being described that way in a simplified MWE. Either way, I'll edit and retract the downvote, since it's clearly not as cut-and-dried to everybody as it was to me on first read.

Answer (score 2):

If `z1` is a list (as indicated in the question), then does the following do what you want:

```
z1 = {1, 2, 3};
xy = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
Flatten[{#, z1}] & /@ xy
(* {{x1, y1, 1, 2, 3}, {x2, y2, 1, 2, 3}, {x3, y3, 1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Or should the output be as follows:

```
z = {z1, z2, z3};
xy = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
Flatten[{#, zz}] & /@ xy /. zz -> z
(* {{x1, y1, {z1, z2, z3}}, {x2, y2, {z1, z2, z3}}, {x3, y3, {z1, z2, z3}}} *)
```