# I Want to Prepend the Row Number of the Matrix to All Elements within That Row

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a matrix of nested lists that looks like this:

```
matrix =
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 0}},
{{2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}, {0, 1}},
{{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 7}}}
```

and I want to Prepend the row number 'x' to each of the elements within each row like this:

```
{{{x, 1, 2}, {x, 3, 4}, {x, 5, 6}, {x, 7, 8}, {x, 9, 0}},
{{x, 2, 3}, {x, 4, 5}, {x, 6, 7}, {x, 8, 9}, {x, 0, 1}},
{{x, 1, 3}, {x, 2, 4}, {x, 3, 5}, {x, 4, 6}, {x, 5, 7}}}
```

so that the final product looks like this:

```
{{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 8}, {1, 9, 0}},
{{2, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 6, 7}, {2, 8, 9}, {2, 0, 1}},
{{3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {3, 5, 7}}}
```

I have played around with something like `MapIndexed[Prepend[#,x]&,matrix,{3}]` which successfully gets me to the intermediate matrix as described above where "x" is prepended, but I can't figure out how to make "x" conditionally equal the index of the row.

Your help is very much appreciated! Thanks so much in advance!!!

Best regards,
Taylor

Comment: `MapIndexed[Prepend[#, First[#2]] &, matrix, {2}]`

Comment: @andre314 That gives me a "1" Prepended to each row, but outside the existing elements:
`{{1, {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}, {9,0}},
{1, {2,3}, {4,5}, {6,7}, {8,9}, {0,1},
{1, {1,3}, {2,4}, {3,5}, {4,6}, {5,7}}}`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194395/compilation-of-a-2d-array-and-a-1d-array

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is to use [`PadLeft`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadLeft):

```
PadLeft[
    matrix,
    Dimensions[matrix] + {0, 0, 1},
    List /@ List /@ Range[Length[matrix]]
]
```

> {{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 8}, {1, 9, 0}}, {{2, 2, 3}, {2, 4,
> 5}, {2, 6, 7}, {2, 8, 9}, {2, 0, 1}}, {{3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}, {3,
> 4, 6}, {3, 5, 7}}}

Comment: This seemed to give me errors:
"Thread: Objects of unequal length in {1}+{0,0,1} cannot be combined." and
"PadLeft: List of machine-sized integers expected at position 2 in PadLeft"

This was the output when I ran the exact code you posted:
`PadLeft[ (matrix), {1} + {0,0,1}, {{{1}}} ]`

Answer (score 3):

#### Updated

Here are three other ways of doing it.

```
matrix =
  {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 0}}, 
   {{2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}, {0, 1}}, 
   {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 7}}};

indxs = Range @ Length @ matrix;

MapThread[Table[{#2, Splice @ pair}, {pair, #1}]&, {matrix, indxs}]

MapThread[Function[pair, {#2, Splice @ pair}] /@ #1&, {matrix, indxs}]

MapIndexed[Function[pair, {#2[[1]], Splice @ pair}] /@ #1&, matrix]
```

All give the result

> ```
> {{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 8}, {1, 9, 0}}, 
>  {{2, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 6, 7}, {2, 8, 9}, {2, 0, 1}}, 
>  {{3, 1, 3}, {3, 2,4}, {3, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {3, 5, 7}}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This combines andre's idea in the comments and Carl's idea:

```
MapIndexed[PadLeft[#1, {Automatic, 3}, #2] &, matrix]
   {{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 8}, {1, 9, 0}},
    {{2, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 6, 7}, {2, 8, 9}, {2, 0, 1}},
    {{3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {3, 5, 7}}}
```

Comment: The `{Automatic, 3}` truncates the first two columns from matrix with no other change
`{{{5,6}, {7,8}, {9,0}}, {{6,7}, {8,9}, {0,1}, {{3,5}, {4,6}, {5,7}}}`
Changing to `{Automatic, 6}` gives me a "1" Prepended to each row, but outside the existing elements as happened above with other solutions:
`{{1, {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}, {9,0}}, {1, {2,3}, {4,5}, {6,7}, {8,9}, {0,1}, {1, {1,3}, {2,4}, {3,5}, {4,6}, {5,7}}}`

Thanks for the effort though! Still trying things out.

Comment: I was assuming the matrices in your list all had two columns, which is why I used the `{Automatic, 3}` setting in `PadLeft[]`.  The example in your comment, @Taylor, does not match this pattern, but `MapIndexed[PadLeft[#1, {Automatic, 3}, #2] &, {{{5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 0}}, {{6, 7}, {8, 9}, {0, 1}}, {{3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 7}}}]` works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[matrix]     
matrix = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 0}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, 
  {8, 9}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 7}}};

MapIndexed[Prepend[First @ #2] /@ # &] @ matrix
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 8}, {1, 9, 0}},
>  {{2, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 6, 7}, {2, 8, 9}, {2, 0, 1}},
>  {{3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {3, 5, 7}}}
> ```

You can also use

```
MapIndexed[Flatten /@ Thread[{First@#2, #}] &, matrix]

% == %%
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: As what happened with @andre314's solution, that also only gives me a "1" Prepended to each row, but outside the existing elements:
`{{1, {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}, {9,0}}, {1, {2,3}, {4,5}, {6,7}, {8,9}, {0,1}, {1, {1,3}, {2,4}, {3,5}, {4,6}, {5,7}}}`

Thanks for the effort though! Still trying things out.

Comment: @TaylorMinckley, posted methods give the desired result in versions 11.3.0 (Windows 10 84 bit) and 12.2.0 (Wolfram Cloud). You might want to try starting with a fresh kernel.

Comment: thank you! Sorry, I'm new to Mathematica. Ill try refreshing my kernel (? gotta go google what that means...). I really appreciate your help and patience. I did figure out how to get it to work on my end, though using `MapIndexed[Prepend[#, Part[#2, 2]] &, 
  matrix, {3}]`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work, using:
`MapIndexed[Prepend[#, Part[#2, 2]] &, matrix, {3}]`

and as @kglr mentioned in the comments here, other posted solutions may work on a fresh kernel.

Comment: If `MapIndexed[Prepend[#, Part[#2, 2]] &, matrix, {3}]` gives you the desired result; then `matrix` in your question should have an additional pair of braces; i.e., `matrix =
{{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 0}},
{{2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}, {0, 1}},
{{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 7}}}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Two other possibilities:

```
Block[{i = 1, p}, p = Prepend[i++] /@ # &; p /@ matrix]
```

and

```
ReplacePart[matrix, {i_, j_} :> Prepend[i] @ matrix[[i, j]]]
```

Both produce

```
{
 {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 8}, {1, 9, 0}},
 {{2, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 6, 7}, {2, 8, 9}, {2, 0, 1}},
 {{3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {3, 5, 7}}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MapIndexed[Flatten[{First@#2, #1}] &, matrix, {2}]

(* {
    {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 6}, {1, 7, 8}, {1, 9, 0}},
    {{2, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 6, 7}, {2, 8, 9}, {2, 0, 1}},
    {{3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {3, 5, 7}}
   } *)
```

**Original Answer**

```
MapIndexed[ArrayFlatten@{{First@#2, #1}} &]@matrix
```